# removing words starts with an upper case

Tags: python-2.7, startswith

so i am new to python and i want to filter out all the words in a text which starts with an uppercase letter so with my limited knowledge to python i did this :

```
def filterupper(text):
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    filteredupper = [w for w in text not in startswith(upper)]
return filteredupper
```

and this error came

```
 File "<pyshell#58>", line 3, in filterupper
filteredupper = [w for w in text not in startswith(upper)]
```

NameError: global name 'startswith' is not defined

so i tried this:

```
def filterupper(text):
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    filteredupper = [w for w in text not in upper]
return filteredupper
```

and this error came:

```
File "<pyshell#55>", line 3, in filterupper
filteredupper = [w for w in text not in upper]
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

so can any one tells me how remove words starts with an uppercase, and tell me what i did wrong in these codes

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) to check if the letter is lowercase:

```
def filterupper(text):
    return " ".join([word for word in text.split() if word[0].islower()])
```

---

```
>>> filterupper("My name is Bob And I am Cool")
"name is am"
>>>
```